# How to get function onFieldSuccess for jQuery Validation Engine

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using a jQuery Validation Plugin/Engine, called: jQuery.validationEngine.

[Posabsolute | jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)

There is a function called: onFieldSuccess and onFieldFailure but I cant get them to work.
This can also come because I'm now doing jQuery for a little while and do not have much experience, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

The only diecription on this function is: [Description functions onFieldSuccess/onFieldFailure](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/pull/473)

The normal functions and functionality are working like a charm.
What I have now is:

```
function testing() {
    alert('Fail');
```

}

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    jQuery("#login-form").validationEngine('attach', {
        promptPosition: 'topLeft', scroll: true,
            bindMethod: "on",
            ajaxFormValidation: true,
            //onFieldSuccess: testing,
            onFieldFailure: testing,
            onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: before_Login_Call,
            onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidation_Login_Callback
    });
    $("#login-form").bind("jqv.field.result", function(event, field, errorFound, prompText){ console.log(field) })
```

});

Comment: Which jQuery version you are using? As from 1.7 `live` is deprecated and should be replaced with `on`.

Comment: @Nazariy Thanks for the tip. I'm Currently using the 1.7.2 version (CDN).

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in your console? As I can see from example `$(document).ready(function() {...` is not closed properly. Also you should be very careful when commenting JavaScript object properties,last property should not end with comma.

Comment: In your example you are referencing to undefined methods `FieldSuccess`and `FieldFailure`

Comment: @Nazariy Sorry that whas my mistake, i didn't copy/past the code correctly. I updated my code above to the current state. And Yes i do get something back in the console.. I can get the hole field back in the console same for the hole event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

It's really easy.

Just set in the core `.js` file the options like this and you're done:

```
onFieldSuccess: true,
onFieldFailure: true,

addSuccessCssClassToField: 'inputbox-success',
addFailureCssClassToField: 'inputbox-error',
```

The two below (`addSuccessCssClassToField` and `addFailureCssClassToField`) are the two css classes the will be used when there is an error.

You can set this in the core `.js` file or you can override the options when you call the validator.

Hopes this also helps someone else.
If you have a question about this, I'll be happy to help you out.